# Letter Change using Python

Tags: python

Problem statement:

> Have the function `LetterChanges(str)` take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

My Python program is:

```
def LetterChanges(str):
    for i in range(0,len(str)):
        a=ord(str[i])
        if a==122:
            str=str.replace(str[i],'a',1)
        elif a==90:
            str=str.replace(str[i],'a',1)
        elif (a>=65 and a<=90) or (a>=97 and a<=122):
            a=a+1
            char=chr(a)
            str=str.replace(str[i],char,1)
    for i in range(0,len(str)):
        if str[i]=='a':
            str=str.replace(str[i],'A',1)
        elif str[i]=='e':
            str=str.replace(str[i],'E',1)
        elif str[i]=='i':
            str=str.replace(str[i],'I',1)
        elif str[i]=='o':
            str=str.replace(str[i],'O',1)
        elif str[i]=='u':
            str=str.replace(str[i],'U',1)
    return(str)

print LetterChanges(raw_input())
```

The problem with my code is that, when I input `sen`, the output was `tfo` which was correct.

But when I gave `sent` as my input, I got the wrong output.

Comment: So the input cz should become dA right?

Comment: if the input is 'sen' you told o/p will be 'tfo', so what about capitalize ?

Comment: I suggest you build a completely new String, not modify the existing one (which is what you're almost doing anyway, despite the problem statement, because strings are immutable)

Comment: Do not use 'CamelCase' for method names, only for 'Classes'. Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is here :[silpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10062865/silpa-sivadas)
when you are replacing you have not cared about indices where character is replacing so how it is going when you give `sent` input 
after replacing n we get string like `tfot` now in next iteration next letter you encounter  in your  original string is `t` so it will replace the first letter that is `t` in the replaced string so . "tfot" becomes "ufot" and last t is not being replaced

Answer (score 2):

here an another try :

```
def prgrm(n):
    k = ""
    for i in n:
        nxt = chr(97 if i == 'z' else ord(i)+1)
        if nxt in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
            nxt = nxt.capitalize()
        k += nxt
    print(k)

prgrm('sen')
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional programming take, without using ord() or a loop, will work with presence of other non alphabetic characters I think:

```
def LetterChanges(str):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    lowers = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
    all = lowers.upper() + lowers
    # Map all alphabetical characters
    nxt_str = "".join(map(lambda x: all[all.index(x) + 1] if x in all else x, str))
    # Map the vowels
    return "".join(map(lambda x: x.upper() if x in vowels else x, nxt_str))

print(LetterChanges("sentdZ"))
tfOUEA
```

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the 't' twice in your string, first the s is replaced by 't' and after that 't' is replaced again by 'u' also the first replacement in the string

```
def LetterChanges(line): 
    result = ""
    for i in line:
        a=ord(i)
        if a == 122 or a == 90:
            result += 'A'
        elif (a >= 65 and a <= 90) or (a >= 97 and a <= 122):
            a = a + 1
            char = chr(a)
            if char in ('e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
                char = char.upper()
            result += char
        else:
            result += i
    return(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with using `re`:

```
import re

def letter_changes(my_string):
    in_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
    out_letters = "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyza"

    letter_dict1 = {x:y for x,y in zip(in_letters, out_letters)}
    letter_dict2 = {'a':'A', 'e':'E', 'i':'I', 'o':'O', 'u':'U'}

    for l_dict in [letter_dict1, letter_dict2]:
        pattern = re.compile("|".join(l_dict.keys()))
        my_string = pattern.sub(lambda m: l_dict[re.escape(m.group(0))], my_string)

    return my_string
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line 
`str=str.replace(str[i],char,1)` with 
`str = str[:i] + char + str[i+1:]`
Reason for this problem answered by @Pankaj78691 is correct!!

Answer (score 0):

**This is another way to write your code:-**

```
def rep_cap(sent):

    sent_rp = ''.join([chr(c) for c in [x+1 for x in [ord(c) for c in sent]]]).replace('{','a') #This thing is done to convert a to b .... z to a 

    final_output = ""

    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    for i in sent_rp:
        if i in vowels:
            final_output = final_output+i.upper() #convert vowels to upper case
        else :
            final_output = final_output+i

    return final_output   

sent = raw_input("Enter a sentence:")

print rep_cap(sent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the algorithm.

```
def LetterChanges(str):
    result = ''
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

    for s in str:
        if s.isalpha():
            if ord(s) == 122: #ASCII code of 'z'
                next_letter = chr(97)
            else:
                next_letter = chr(ord(s)+1)

            if next_letter in vowels:
                result += next_letter.upper()
            else:
                result += next_letter

        else:
            result += s

    return result
```